# React - Dynamically appending click handlers in useEffect() + redux props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, append, addeventlistener

I've created a functional component that displays two variables along with two buttons. Now, I'm creating those buttons in useEffect() by creating elements and appending them and adding click handlers to them through `element.addEventListener()` method. Now those click handlers will update the counters based on the props from the redux store.

The issue is that, each time we trigger the button. In the click handler, I'm always getting the initial state of the redux store even though the store variables are being updated each time I dispatch an action.

Example: 
Initial state { start: 1, end: 4 } 
Clicked on right button: state { start: 5, end: 8 } - but still, I'll be reading the variables as `start: 1` and `end: 4` when I click the right button next time.

Please find the code below:

TestPage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { incrementCounter, updatePagination } from '../redux/Actions';

function TestPage(props) {

    const handleRight = () => {
        alert('handle right');
        let startCount = props.paginationWindow.start;
        let endCount = props.paginationWindow.end;

        console.log("TEST - RIGHT - start count: " + startCount);

        startCount += 4;
        endCount += 4;

        props.updatePagination({
            start: startCount,
            end: endCount
        })
    }

    const handleLeft = () => {
        alert('handle left');
        let startCount = props.paginationWindow.start;
        let endCount = props.paginationWindow.end;

        console.log("TEST - LEFT - start count: " + startCount);

        startCount -= 4;
        endCount -= 4;

        props.updatePagination({
            start: startCount,
            end: endCount
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let leftContainer = document.getElementById("leftButtonContainer");
        let rightContainer = document.getElementById("rightButtonContainer");

        let leftArrow = document.querySelector('#videoLeftArrow');
        let rightArrow = document.querySelector('#videoRightArrow');

        if (!leftArrow) {
            alert('left creation');
            leftArrow = document.createElement('span');
            leftArrow.setAttribute('id', 'videoLeftArrow');
            leftArrow.setAttribute('class', 'pagination-left-arrow-container');
            leftArrow.setAttribute('title', 'Show Previous Video Screens');
            leftArrow.addEventListener('click', handleLeft);
            leftContainer.appendChild(leftArrow);
            let leftArrowIcon = document.createElement('span');
            leftArrowIcon.setAttribute('class', 'material-icons pagination-left-arrow');
            leftArrowIcon.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_left";
            leftArrow.appendChild(leftArrowIcon);
        }

        if (!rightArrow) {
            alert('right creation');
            rightArrow = document.createElement('span');
            rightArrow.setAttribute('id', 'videoRightArrow');
            rightArrow.setAttribute('class', 'pagination-right-arrow-container');
            rightArrow.setAttribute('title', 'Show Next Video Screens');
            rightArrow.addEventListener('click', handleRight);
            rightContainer.appendChild(rightArrow);
            let rightArrowIcon = document.createElement('span');
            rightArrowIcon.setAttribute('class', 'material-icons pagination-right-arrow');
            rightArrowIcon.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_right";
            rightArrow.appendChild(rightArrowIcon);
        }

    }, [props.paginationWindow])

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ "marginTop": "20px", "display": "inline-flex" }}>
                <div id="leftButtonContainer">
                    {/* rendered left button comes here */}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Pagination Start: {props.paginationWindow.start}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Pagination End: {props.paginationWindow.end}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="rightButtonContainer">
                    {/* rendered right button comes here */}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    counter: state.app.counter,
    paginationWindow: state.app.paginationWindow
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    incrementCounter: (data) => dispatch(incrementCounter(data)),
    updatePagination: (data) => dispatch(updatePagination(data))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestPage)
```

Reducer.js

```
import {
    UPDATE_PAGINATION
} from './ActionTypes'

const initialState = {
    paginationWindow: {
        start: 1,
        end: 4
    }
}

const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_PAGINATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                paginationWindow: {
                    start: action.payload.start,
                    end: action.payload.end
                }
            };

        default: return state;
    }
}

export default appReducer;
```

Note: Instead of creating and appending the Left and Right buttons, if I just include them in the JSX directly with click handlers, the functionality is working fine without any issues.

TestPage.js (JSX)

```
return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ "marginTop": "20px", "display": "inline-flex" }}>
                <div id="leftButtonContainer">
                    <Button id="leftButton" onClick={handleLeft} variant="contained">
                        Left
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Pagination Start: {props.paginationWindow.start}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Pagination End: {props.paginationWindow.end}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="rightButtonContainer">
                    <Button id="rightButton" onClick={handleRight} variant="contained">
                        Right
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

What might be the cause of this and proper way to append dynamic elements with click handlers which involve the update of redux store variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your effect does not depend on props.paginationWindow but on handleLeft and handleRight, you can use useCallback to (re)create these functions when paginationWindow.end or paginationWindow.start changes:

```
const { paginationWindow, updatePagination } = props;
const handleRight = useCallback(() => {
  alert('handle right');
  let startCount = paginationWindow.start;
  let endCount = paginationWindow.end;

  console.log(
    'TEST - RIGHT - start count: ' + startCount
  );

  startCount += 4;
  endCount += 4;

  updatePagination({
    start: startCount,
    end: endCount,
  });
}, [
  paginationWindow.end,
  paginationWindow.start,
  updatePagination,
]);

const handleLeft = useCallback(() => {
  alert('handle left');
  let startCount = paginationWindow.start;
  let endCount = paginationWindow.end;

  console.log('TEST - LEFT - start count: ' + startCount);

  startCount -= 4;
  endCount -= 4;

  updatePagination({
    start: startCount,
    end: endCount,
  });
}, [
  paginationWindow.end,
  paginationWindow.start,
  updatePagination,
]);

useEffect(() => {
  let leftContainer = document.getElementById(
    'leftButtonContainer'
  );
  let rightContainer = document.getElementById(
    'rightButtonContainer'
  );

  let leftArrow = document.querySelector(
    '#videoLeftArrow'
  );
  let rightArrow = document.querySelector(
    '#videoRightArrow'
  );

  if (!leftArrow) {
    alert('left creation');
    leftArrow = document.createElement('span');
    leftArrow.setAttribute('id', 'videoLeftArrow');
    leftArrow.setAttribute(
      'class',
      'pagination-left-arrow-container'
    );
    leftArrow.setAttribute(
      'title',
      'Show Previous Video Screens'
    );
    leftArrow.addEventListener('click', handleLeft);
    leftContainer.appendChild(leftArrow);
    let leftArrowIcon = document.createElement('span');
    leftArrowIcon.setAttribute(
      'class',
      'material-icons pagination-left-arrow'
    );
    leftArrowIcon.innerHTML = 'keyboard_arrow_left';
    leftArrow.appendChild(leftArrowIcon);
  }

  if (!rightArrow) {
    alert('right creation');
    rightArrow = document.createElement('span');
    rightArrow.setAttribute('id', 'videoRightArrow');
    rightArrow.setAttribute(
      'class',
      'pagination-right-arrow-container'
    );
    rightArrow.setAttribute(
      'title',
      'Show Next Video Screens'
    );
    rightArrow.addEventListener('click', handleRight);
    rightContainer.appendChild(rightArrow);
    let rightArrowIcon = document.createElement('span');
    rightArrowIcon.setAttribute(
      'class',
      'material-icons pagination-right-arrow'
    );
    rightArrowIcon.innerHTML = 'keyboard_arrow_right';
    rightArrow.appendChild(rightArrowIcon);
  }
}, [handleLeft, handleRight]);
```

Not sure if it's a good idea to manipulate DOM elements and why they are not React components but I'm sure you have your reasons.

The code above still won't work because `if (!leftArrow) {` will only create the elements if they don't exist when `handleLeft` changes you don't remove the event listener and add it again. Maybe you can use the cleanup function of the effect to remove the event listener and always add the event listener in the effect.